# Application crash when I try to open the activity

Tags: java, android, xml

When I press login on my app it should take me to `activity.targa`, but instead it crashes and I can't understand why (My phone is Redmi Note 7, but it also crashes on Mi A2)

activity.targa:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#FFFFFF"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context=".TargaActivity">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <com.google.android.material.circularreveal.CircularRevealFrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <TextView.../>

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout.../>

    <TextView.../>

    <TextView.../>

</LinearLayout>

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header"
    app:menu="@menu/drawer_menu" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

and TargaActivity:

```
package com.efficientparking.efficientparking;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.TextView;
import androidx.appcompat.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.core.view.GravityCompat;
import androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout;
import java.util.HashMap;

public class TargaActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private DrawerLayout drawer;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_targa);
    androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);

    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    if(drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)){
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

}
```

`androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);`
I had to change here since Android Studio gave me troubles because he was saying that the following method (`setSupportActionBar(toolbar)`) didn't exist.

But now as soon as I try to get into `activity_targa`, app crashes.

Android studio actually load the xml and it seems nice, but then I compile the apk and it crashes.

Log file:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.efficientparking/com.efficientparking.efficientparking.TargaActivity}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3311)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3460)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2047)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:224)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7590)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
at com.efficientparking.efficientparking.TargaActivity.onCreate(TargaActivity.java:22)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7880)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3286)
... 11 more
```

Comment: ClassCastException: android.widget.Toolbar cannot be cast to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar looks like you are mixing up two different classes of Toolbar.

Comment: androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar); here you assing one type of Toolbar, but your findViewById returns another type

Comment: Yes but it doesn't work even if I change from Toolbar to androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `android.widget.Toolbar` in both `xml` and `java`, as `setSupportActionBar` takes `android.widget.Toolbar`

Comment: If I use android.widget.Toolbar it says that setSupportActionBar() requires androidx.appcompact.widget.Toolbar